# Regexp performancing in different languages

Tags: regex, programming-languages

If in `PHP`, some regex pattern is better for performancing than second pattern, this means that this pattern will also better in `JAVA's` or in `javascript's` or in `postgreSQL's` regex?

That is, in different language/DB, regexp working is same or differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not the same perfomace. I've found article about benchmarking regex on various languages. You may find it useful.

- http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/performance.php?test=regexdna&sort=elapsed
- http://lh3lh3.users.sourceforge.net/reb.shtml

and here you will find some information about handling regexs in various languages

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Also you may want to read this:

[Regex performances between languages or libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127089/regex-performances-between-languages-or-libraries)